# how can I populate data table with values from a database

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, datatable

I wanted to populate data table with the value taken from the database. I want to use Select condition with the values taken from textbox.. I have written the following code in C#, please tell me whether it is a right approach. It is showing exception about connection string.. but I wanted to know whether my approach is correct or not.. please do comment.

```
public partial class searchsale : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\rdb.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");

            conn.Open();
            string scriptname = TextBox1.Text;
            string accnum = TextBox2.Text;
            string sql = @"select scriptname,accnum,Quantity,price from transac where scriptname = @sn, accnum = @an and transactio = 'Sell'";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = sql;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@an", accnum);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sn", scriptname);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            DataTable dt = GetDataTable(sql);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("error" + ex.ToString());
        }

    }
    private DataTable GetDataTable (string sql)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString()))
        {
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
            da.Fill(dt);
        }
        return dt;
    }
}
```

Comment: @user2946329 : "Connection property has not been initialized. at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand" this is the exception which I am getting... I will correct it , but I want to know whether I am using the right approach or not, Plssss do have a look at the code and let me know whether I am going in a right way or not to solve the problem.. Thank u

Comment: write and or create a static class called SqlHelper for example I will post a simple example on how to do this and you can call it from anywhere in your code when you want to fill the datable and return it..

Comment: use the app.config to add your connection string what I posted is very simple to read as well as follow assuming you know how to call methods of a static class.. also instead of calling this `DataTable dt = GetDataTable(sql);` you can call `var dt =  SqlDBHelper.ExecuteDataSet(` passing the proper variables and it will return you a loaded datatable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error with your code is because you have not set the connection property of your command .

and for using data table the most simple way is using :

```
try
{
    var connection = @"your connection string";
    //your command
    var command = "your command";
    var dataAdapter = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(command, connection);
    var dataTable = new DataTable();

    //Get data
    dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
}
catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException sqlEx)
{
    //Use sqlEx.Number to hanlde excception more specific
    //for example if sqlEx.Number -1 => Could Not Connect to Server.
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}
```

Comment: sir I need use the select command which will make use of content in the textbox.. will u tell whether what I have done is a right approach or not??

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in your below code line for `GetDataTable (string sql)` method. You will have to use `ConnectionString` property. I would suggest you to read about `ADO.NET` more from MSDN.

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString()))
        {
```

Should be

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString
```

It should look like

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new 
SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
        {
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static class SqlDBHelper
{
    public static DataSet ExecuteDataSet(string sql, CommandType cmdType, params SqlParameter[] parameters)
    {
        using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
        using (SqlConnection connStr = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DbConn"].ConnectionString))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connStr))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = cmdType;
            foreach (var item in parameters)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add(item);
            }

            try
            {
                cmd.Connection.Open();
                new SqlDataAdapter(cmd).Fill(ds);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            return ds;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I use this on a daily basis it's a life saver once I added it to my own utils class

Answer (score 0):

your code looks  right except the connection string. You have declared the connection string at the beginning  as

```
  SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data      Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\rdb.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
```

But in your connection initialization it looks like you are getting it from App config file.

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new  SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString()))
```

So instead of having connection in your code put it in the app config file and remove the connection from your code
something like this

```
     <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectionString" 
    connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\rdb.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Thank you,

Birhanu