# How to store database resultset?

Tags: vb.net

I want to know which is the best way to store database value in `vb.net`, For example, I've this code:

```
 Dim conn As MySqlConnection = Connection() 'Return a connection obj
 conn.Open()

 Dim transaction = conn.BeginTransaction
 Dim cmd = New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tb ORDER BY ID")
 Dim ResultSet = Cmd.ExecuteReader

 If ResultSet.HasRows Then

    Do While ResultSet.Read

       'Here the value should be store

    Loop

 End if
```

How you can see I take all table from my database, now I want store each records in a structure that allow me to access it like the table. An array is good for do this? A list? Which is the best way?

Comment: There is no best way. As an option you can use a `DataTable` Also you can store values in a generic `List`

Comment: Uhm, you suggest to use a DataTable?

Comment: Where do you want to use the result?

Comment: In addition to DataTables you could also think about an object relational mapper like [Entity Framework](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?174,601264,601264)

Comment: I need to store the result 'cause in the next time I need to iterate through a (list?) well, where the records is stored.. for compare some specific field.

Comment: So `DataTable` and `List(Of T)` are good options. But if I need a `DataTable` I'll create it using a `DataAdapter` and also if I need a `List(Of T)` I'll use Entity Framwork. Also you need create your `List(Of T)` from your `DataTable`.

Comment: ..But, how I can associate the column name and value in datatable?

Comment: You are welcome, To fill a `DataTable` using a `DataAdapter` you may find this answer helpful: [how can I populate data table with values from a database](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32571002/3110834)

Comment: I should add the DataAdapter or replace the MySqlCommand? 'cause if I replace MySqlCommand I can't execute the reader on cmd variable

Comment: DataTable are memory objects with more or less the same behaviour of persistent Table in DataBase. You can fill it with `DataTable.Load(dataReader)`, and iterate with `foreach DataRow row in DataTable.Rows`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no best way. You have different options. For example:

- As an option you can use a `DataTable`
- Also you can store values in a generic `List(Of T)`.

If you prefer working with `DataTable` it will be more simple to use  `DataAdapter` to fill the `DataTable`. This way you can also create your `List(Of T)` from your `DataTable`.

Example of Using DataDapter to fill DataTable

```
Dim Connection = "Connection String"
Dim Command = "SELECT * FROM Category"
Dim Adapter = New SqlDataAdapter(Command, Connection)
Dim Table = New DataTable()
Adapter.Fill(Table)
```

This way the `DataTable` will have columns with name of columns in your result set.

Also you can fill your data in a `List(Of T)` using the `DataTable` this way:

```
Dim ListOfCategory = Table.Rows.Cast(Of DataRow) _
                          .Select(Function(Row)
                                     Return New Category With 
                                     {
                                         .Id = Row.Field(Of Integer)("Id"),
                                         .Name = Row.Field(Of String)("Name")
                                     }
                                  End Function).ToList()
```

**Note**

If can change the way you are writing your application, you can use **Entity Framework** as a good option to work with data.

Comment: I've no experience with entity framework unfortunately